# How close can I plant a clematis to a small climbing rose

Tags: planting, roses, climbers

I am planting a clematis with Rosa Creme de la Creme.  I do not have room to leave 3ft between the two.  Can I plant them closer

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which clematis variety. On the assumption the Clematis is a smaller cultivar, or one that needs pruning back to 9  inches in winter, and you want it to climb up the rose, plant as close as 6-9 inches away from the rose roots - easier to plant both at the same time, putting the rose in first, then the clematis, so you don't accidentally damage the roots of either. You don't say which Clematis it is though; if it's a species one like C. montana that gets 35 feet, then they can't be planted together because the Clematis will completely cover and swamp the rose. Equally, it wouldn't be wise to plant an evergreen Clematis close to a rose either...

Answer (score 0):

I would say you can plant them as close as you like, so long as there is enough room for both sets of roots to spread out where they want to.

The clematis will climb up the rose whether it is 3 feet way or right next to it. Trying to keep them separate will be a waste of effort!